# ElasticSearch query nested path filter OR

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following index:

```
PUT /ab11
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "product_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "data": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "p_id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


PUT /ab11/_doc/1
{
  "product_id": "123",
  "data": [
    {
      "p_id": "a"
    },
    {
      "p_id": "b"
    },
    {
      "p_id": "c"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to do query like following sql does(NOTE: I want to do `filter` not `query`, because I don't care about `score`) :

```
select * from abc11 where data.pid = "a" or data.pid = "b"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this because the `terms` query has `OR` semantics by default:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "data",
      "query": {
        "terms": {
          "data.p_id": [
            "a",
            "b"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, select all documents which have either `"a"` or `"b"` in their `data.p_id` nested docs.

Comment: Thanks @val for the great answer! The returned docs has `_score` as 1.0, I would ask this is a calcuated score(with scoring process) or default without scoring process

Comment: Since the query is a yes/no query and there's no full-text matching involved, the score can only be 1.